# python vlc audio filter

Tags: python, audio, vlc, python-vlc

I have been trying to enable an audio filter in vlc.

However it doesn't seems to be making any difference in the audio.

I can get video filters to work but it's just the audio filters that doesn't seem to be working.

My code is as follow:

```
import pafy
import vlc, time

sound = "01. Fairyland In Reality.mp3"
vlc_instance = vlc.Instance("--audio-filter=karaoke")
player = vlc.MediaPlayer(vlc_instance)

media = vlc_instance.media_new(sound)
player.set_media(media)

player.play()

time.sleep(1.5)
duration = player.get_length() / 1000
time.sleep(duration)
```